# How can I limit the number of document that a user can create in firestore roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried using resource.size but it does not work my rules are like this

```
 allow create: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid &&
        request.resource.data.name is string 
        && request.resource.data.phoneNumber is number
        && request.resource.data.age is number
        && request.resource.data.gander == 'Male'||request.resource.data.gander == 'Female'
        && resource.size() <= 12;
```

I want to allow every user to create 12 patient is there a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resource, as well as request.resource point to documents, not collections.
While you can perform a get on a document path, you cannot do so on a collection.

So you will need to maintain the count of created patient for each user as a doc, for example in /users/uid add field patientCount. Then in your security rule you can check this field:

```
function canCreate(uid) {
  var userDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/uid);
  return userDoc.data.patientCount < 12;
}

allow create: if canCreate(request.auth.uid);
```

To maintain the patientCount, I detailed the multiple ways in [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-documents-in-firestore-a0527f792d04).